# HTTP Performance Test in C#

Tags: c#, performance, http

I wrote a script to test how long it takes to make requests against a url.  It takes a list of urls, an array of concurrent requests, and a number of times to attempt the test.  How could I improve on this?

```
//https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp

string baseUrl = "http://localhost";
void Main()
{
    var urls = new string[] { 
        "/some/end/point",
    };

    var concurrentRequests = new int[]{ 1, 5, 25, 50, 100, 500, 1000};
    var numberOfTurns = 10;
    RunTests(urls, concurrentRequests, numberOfTurns);

}

private void RunTests(string[] urls, int[] concurrentRequests,  int numberOfTimes = 1)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++)
    {
        RunFor(urls, concurrentRequests);
    }
}
private void RunFor(string[] urls, int[] concurrentRequests)
{
    concurrentRequests.ToList().ForEach( e =>   
    {
         RunTest(urls, e);
    }); 
}
private void RunTest(string[] sites, int iterations, string description = "")
{
    var action = GetAction();

    var watch = new Stopwatch(); 
   // Construct started tasks
   Task<bool>[] tasks = new Task<bool>[sites.Count()];
   watch.Start();

   for(int j = 0; j < iterations; j++)
   {
        for (int i = 0; i < sites.Count(); i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(action, sites[i]);
        }
   }
   try
   {
       Task.WaitAll(tasks);
   }
   catch (AggregateException e)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("\nThe following exceptions have been thrown by WaitAll()");
       for (int j = 0; j < e.InnerExceptions.Count; j++)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("\n-------------------------------------------------\n{0}", e.InnerExceptions[j].ToString());
       }
   }
   finally
   {
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("\"{0}|{1}|{2}\", ",sites.Count(), iterations, watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
   }
}
private Func<object, bool>  GetAction()
{
    baseUrl = baseUrl.Trim('/');
    return (object obj) =>
   {
        var str = (string)obj;
        var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
        client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator();
        var request = new RestRequest(str, Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "text/html");
        var response = client.Execute(request);     
        return (response != null);
   };
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default number of concurrent requests to the same server ([`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx)) is only 2. So I believe most of your tests are going to be limited by that and not by the server you're trying to test.

You should change the value to something larger (probably `concurrentRequests.Max()`).

---

```
concurrentRequests.ToList().ForEach( e =>   
{
     RunTest(urls, e);
});
```

I don't see any reason to use `List.ForEach()` here (or pretty much anywhere else). Normal `foreach` is simpler and more efficient (no need to copy the array to a `List`):

```
foreach (int requests in concurrentRequests)
{
     RunTest(urls, requests);
}
```

I have also change the name of the iteration variable to `request` to make the code somewhat more readable.

---

```
for(int j = 0; j < iterations; j++)
for (int i = 0; i < sites.Count(); i++)
```

You should be consistent regarding whether you put a space after the `for` keyword. The common way is to put a space there.

---

```
tasks[i] = Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(action, sites[i]);
```

This can be simplified to:

```
tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(action, sites[i]);
```

Also, unless few extra allocations are important for you, I would use a lambda here to make the code more type-safe (no more casts in `GetAction`) and clearer (your `GetAction` returns a lambda, my `TestUrl` is a normal method):

```
var url = urls[i];

tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TestUrl(url));
```

Few notes about this code:

- I have changed `sites` to `urls`, it make it consistent between methods and also because I believe that's more correct term.
- The `url` variable is important here, `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TestUrl(urls[i]))` wouldn't work correctly, because the `i` variable is shared among iterations of the loop, while `url` isn't.

---

```
for(int j = 0; j < iterations; j++)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < sites.Count(); i++)
     {
         tasks[i] = Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(action, sites[i]);
     }
}
```

If `iterations` is greater than 1, you're going to overwrite old `Task`s with new ones, which means you're not going to wait for the old tasks to complete. That's not okay.

---

```
Console.WriteLine("\nThe following exceptions have been thrown by WaitAll()");
```

I find it confusing that you use both `\n` and `WriteLine()` for newlines. I would prefer to write it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("The following exceptions have been thrown by WaitAll()");
```

An alternative if you want to be concise is:

```
Console.Write("\nThe following exceptions have been thrown by WaitAll()\n");
```

Answer (score 5):

You're not always using `var` in what I think of as a good way. We should only use the keyword when it's obvious what type the variable is. Consider this line.

> ```
> Task<bool>[] tasks = new Task<bool>[sites.Count()];
> ```

It's completely obvious what `tasks` is because you're newing it up right there on that line. There's no reason not to simplify by using `var`.

But here, you have the opposite problem.

> ```
> var response = client.Execute(request);
> ```

It is **not** obvious what the return type is, so you shouldn't be using `var`.

Answer (score 3):

- I don't see a reason, why you prefer the extension method `Count()` over the `Length` property of the `string[] sites` array.
- Comments should describe **why** something is done and they should be **valid / true**

  ```
  // Construct started tasks
  Task<bool>[] tasks = new Task<bool>[sites.Count()];
  ```

  this comment is

  1. boilerplate code
  2. misleading because neither does the next line construct any task nor `started` tasks.
- If this should be used by others also, you need to validate the input parameters. In the current state, if e.g `sites == null` you will get an `ArgumentNullException`.
- the optional parameter `description` can be removed, because it isn't used at all

Comment: Hmm... I can think of a good reason to use the extension instead of the Length property. If the implementation later changes to use a different IEnumerable, you can still call Count. You'd only have to change the code in one place and it'd still work. The other advice is spot on (as always) though.